# Posição de chapéus parece incorreta em alguns casos

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro, winterbash-2016

Notei que alguns usuários ([exemplo1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/62257/douglas-carvalho)) tem o chapéu numa posição que é impossível de configurar.

Assim, ao acessar [uma página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/171672/abrir-como-administrador-apenas-na-primeira-vez-em-delphi) com participação deste usuário, o chapéu fica numa posição bem estranha.
[Veja imagem abaixo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOYa8.jpg)

Informações adicionais: Uso o Firefox 44.0.2. Revi as configurações do NoScript/Disconnect/ABP pra verificar se alguma atualização removeu minhas liberações para o SOpt. 
Isso me aconteceu já em outros sites da rede.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. A posição que estou vendo aqui é passível de configuração sim. E aqui a "lua" não ficou no canto superior esquerdo como na imagem. Em qual navegador você testou?

Comment: Aqui tambem aparece corretamente: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IUFV.png

Comment: Uso o Firefox @Randrade. Pra mim ainda está mostrando incorretamente. Eu até revi as configurações do NoScript/Disconnect/ADB pra verificar... Vou tentar atualizar o Firefox e verificar novamente. Mas isso me aconteceu já em outros sites da rede.

Comment: @EMBarbosa Estou usando a versão `50.1.0` do Firefox e também está normal. Tentou abrir em outro browser para ver se é algo referente ao browser mesmo?

Comment: @Randrade Atualizei o Firefox e não corrigiu.

Comment: Analisando melhor a imagem do @MarceloBonifazio percebi que a imagem do usuário não é mostrada aqui em nenhum browser. Parece ser um problema daqui.

Comment: Eu não vejo chapéu nenhum em lugar nenhum (além das capturas de tela), o que foi que eu perdi?

Comment: @Renan, vc não viu porque já passou... olha a data da pergunta... Só que ela estava sem resposta. E só hoje eu percebi isso. :(

Answer (score 3):

Descobri o que é: A imagem dos usuários que estão armazenadas no Facebook é que não aparecem aqui e geram essa posição estranha dos chapéus.

Parece que temos um bloqueio do Facebook aqui na empresa.

Então realmente não é um bug. Menos mal. :)